# how to handle routing in asp.net core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i have a two pages Home.cshtml and Job.cshtml

> in Startup file i mange this

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {              
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home", "/{handler?}");
        });


services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Job", "{*url}");
            });
```

i want to open this url for Home.cshtml

```
http://localhost:44004/au/hospital-jobs-in-India
```

and second url is i want to open this in Job.cshtml

```
http://localhost:44004/best-jobs-in-India/Page-3/NewsData
```

Note: Now my issue is that for both url it hit the Job.cshtml
but i want to hit for separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what is the [friendly routes](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes) in Razor pages . As your current route template , `/au` and `/au/` will map to `Home` page it app catches any URL that doesn't map to a physical file , and `/au/hospital-jobs-in-India` will map to `Job` page since the route doesn't match the first friendly route , but it match the `{*url}` route template . You should modify the route based on your requirement , for example ,change the first route template like `/au/{handler?}` .

In addition , you don't need to register `AddRazorPages` multi times , you can directly add multiple `AddPageRoute` inside one `AddRazorPagesOptions` .